# How to find rows that have a specific value in a JSON column (table of values) with JPA Criteria API only (Postgre DB)?

Tags: json, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

Let's assume we have a json column `names` in a PostGreSQL DB. Its content has the following structure:

```
["NameA", "NameB", "NameC"]
```

On Java side, the corresponding column is:

```
@Type(type = "jsonb")
@Column(name = "names")
private List<String> names;
```

I already have a global search request built with JPA Criteria API *but not written as a native query* and I must complete it with new incoming criteria: "name".
To complete the existing query, I must check if the json column "names" contains the value requested by the client ("NameB" for example). If so, the row(s) must be returned.

To do so, I found the PostGre function: "json_array_elements_text" that returns a "set of text" as explained here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html
At first, I tried to use this function with a predicate (with an "equal" or I was looking for a contains like with javax Predicate method) and then in the CriteriaQuery method "where" but the DB returned the error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE
```

I finally tried to write the SQL request for better understanding in a DB browser. It works if the `json_array_elements_text` function is located in the FROM in this way:

```
select ...some columns...
from ...some tables with some inner join... cross join lateral json_array_elements_text(tableAlias.names) as nameElement
where nameElement='ValueB'
```

To sum up: I want the row(s) to be returned if a requested value is part of a table of values.

How can I reproduce this or an equivalent for my need with JPA Criteria API (without writting it as native query)?

Thanks,
liova

Comment: I found this less complex request also works in DB browser: 

SELECT ...some columns...
FROM ...some tables with some inner join..., json_array_elements_text(tableAlias.names) nameElement
WHERE nameElement='ValueB'

But still has to use function in from without native query.

Any idea?